# Checkbox management with bloc pattern - Full code

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use the bloc pattern to manage my set of checkboxes. The bloc has only to store whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Below is the code that can be run to simulate what is happening.

The (wrong) result I'm getting at is that when you update a checkbox, the data is not rendered correctly.

[image: checkbox teste stackoverflow]

Logs

```
First Click in Checkbox 1
I/flutter ( 6239): newMapCheckbox: {1: true}
I/flutter ( 6239): _mapCheckbox: {1: true, 2: false, 3: false}

Second Click in Checkbox 1
I/flutter ( 6239): newMapCheckbox: {1: null}
I/flutter ( 6239): _mapCheckbox: {1: null, 2: false, 3: false}
```

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Checkbox Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ApplicationBloc _bloc = new ApplicationBloc();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Checkbox Test'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _bloc.listItemModel,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ItemModel>> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          List<ItemModel> listItemModel = snapshot.data;

          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: listItemModel.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              ItemModel itemModel = listItemModel[index];
              return ListTile(
                leading: _checkbox(_bloc, itemModel.id),
                title: Text('${itemModel.name}'),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _checkbox(ApplicationBloc _bloc, int idItemModel) {
    // This doesn't render like expected
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.checkboxController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, bool>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Checkbox(
            tristate: true,
            value: snapshot.data[idItemModel],
            onChanged: (value) => _bloc.setCheckbox(
                  <int, bool>{idItemModel: value},
                ),
          );
        } else
          return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}

class ItemModel {
  int id;
  String name;
  ItemModel(this.id, this.name);
}

class ApplicationBloc {
  // List Management
  BehaviorSubject<List<ItemModel>> listModelController =
      BehaviorSubject<List<ItemModel>>();
  Observable<List<ItemModel>> get listItemModel => listModelController.stream;

  // Checkbox Management - Item Model ID and checkbox value
  BehaviorSubject<Map<int, bool>> checkboxController =
      BehaviorSubject<Map<int, bool>>();
  Observable<Map<int, bool>> get mapModelCheckbox => checkboxController.stream;
  Function(Map<int, bool>) get setCheckbox => checkboxController.sink.add;

  List<ItemModel> _listItemModel = List<ItemModel>();
  Map<int, bool> _mapCheckbox = HashMap<int, bool>();

  ApplicationBloc() {
    // Initial data for list and map
    _listItemModel.add(ItemModel(1, 'Item Model 1'));
    _mapCheckbox[1] = false;
    _listItemModel.add(ItemModel(2, 'Item Model 2'));
    _mapCheckbox[2] = false;
    _listItemModel.add(ItemModel(3, 'Item Model 3'));
    _mapCheckbox[3] = false;

    // Insert initial data in controller
    listModelController.add(_listItemModel);
    checkboxController.add(_mapCheckbox);

    // Handler for checkbox state
    checkboxController.stream.listen(setCheckboxHandler);
  }

  setCheckboxHandler(Map<int, bool> newMapCheckbox) {
    // New checkbox value for the itemModel id
    int id = newMapCheckbox.entries.elementAt(0).key;
    bool check = newMapCheckbox.entries.elementAt(0).value;
    if (_mapCheckbox.containsKey(id)) {
      _mapCheckbox[id] = check;
    }
    print('-----------');
    print('newMapCheckbox: $newMapCheckbox');
    print('_mapCheckbox: $_mapCheckbox');
    print('-----------');
  }

  //dispose/close all the streams when we call dispose() method
  void dispose() {
    listModelController.close();
    checkboxController.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to true or false, then why you are using tri-state checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

For what you need, you should only manage two states in the checkboxes.

Taking to code as a base we have something like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter CheckboxListTile',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}

// model amenities.
class Item {
  int id;
  String title;
  Item({this.id, this.title});
  List<String> _amenities = [
    "Item Model 1",
    "Item Model 2",
    "Item Model 3",
  ];

  List<String> getAm(
      Map<int, bool> checkBoxes, Map<int, String> checkAmenities) {
    List<String> _am = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkBoxes[i] != false) {
        print(i);
        print(checkAmenities[i]);
        _am.add(checkAmenities[i]);
      }
    }
    return _am;
  }

  List<Item> getItems() {
    List<Item> _items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < _amenities.length; i++) {
      _items.add(Item(id: i, title: _amenities[i]));
    }
    return _items;
  }
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Item _item = Item();
    List<Item> checkBoxList = _item.getItems();
    AmenitiesBloc _bloc = new AmenitiesBloc();
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('CheckboxListTile demo')),
      body: Container(
        height: 225.0,
        child: Card(child: grupCheck(checkBoxList, _bloc)),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView grupCheck(List<Item> checkBoxList, AmenitiesBloc _bloc) {
    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: checkBoxList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder<Object>(
                    stream: _bloc.checkboxController,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return new CheckboxListTile(
                        activeColor:
                            Colors.green, //Check is true color is green
                        dense: true, //font change
                        value: _bloc._mapCheckbox[index],
                        title: new Text(checkBoxList[index].title),
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity
                            .leading, //Display check box first, remove this line checkbox display last
                        onChanged: (value) =>
                            _bloc.setCheckbox(<int, bool>{index: value}),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

// The bloc

class AmenitiesBloc {
  // Checkbox Management - Item Model ID and checkbox value
  BehaviorSubject<Map<int, bool>> checkboxController =
      BehaviorSubject<Map<int, bool>>();
  Stream<Map<int, bool>> get mapModelCheckbox => checkboxController.stream;
  Function(Map<int, bool>) get setCheckbox => checkboxController.sink.add;
  Item _item = Item();
  Map<int, bool> _mapCheckbox = HashMap<int, bool>();
  Map<int, String> _mapAmenities = HashMap<int, String>();

  AmenitiesBloc() {
    // Initial data for list and map
    List<Item> _theAmenities = _item.getItems();
    for (var i = 0; i < _theAmenities.length; i++) {
      _mapAmenities[i] = _theAmenities[i].title;
      _mapCheckbox[i] = false;
    }
    // Insert initial data in controller
    checkboxController.add(_mapCheckbox);
    checkboxController.stream.listen(setCheckboxHandler);
  }
  // Handler for checkbox state

  setCheckboxHandler(Map<int, bool> newMapCheckbox) {
    // New checkbox value for the itemModel id
    int id = newMapCheckbox.entries.elementAt(0).key;
    bool check = newMapCheckbox.entries.elementAt(0).value;
    if (_mapCheckbox.containsKey(id)) {
      _mapCheckbox[id] = check;
    }

    print('-----------');
    print('newMapCheckbox: $newMapCheckbox');
    print('_mapCheckbox: $_mapCheckbox');
    print('-----------');
    print(_mapCheckbox.length);
    List<String> a = _item.getAm(_mapCheckbox, _mapAmenities);

    print(a.toString());
    print(a.toString().runtimeType);
  }

  //dispose/close all the streams when we call dispose() method
  void dispose() {
    checkboxController.close();
  }
}
```